# odoo 17.0 on windows. Problem with "sassc"

Tags: css, odoo-17, sassc

I'm trying to start a server in odoo (python). However, it launched without css markup. Everything looks like a website from the 2000s

```
The style compilation failed, see the error below. This is an administrator or developer error that must be fixed for the entire database before continuing working.

"Could not execute command 'sassc'This error occurred while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_web' containing:
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/functions.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/mixins_forwardport.scss
    - /web/static/src/scss/bs_mixins_overrides.scss
...
```

I think I've already installed all the mobile libraries, but nothing works. What could be the problem?

I have added libraries like

npm install -g less
npm install -g less-plugin-clean-cs
pip3 install libsass==0.12.3
...

Nothing works. All answers on the Internet under Linux.

Comment: Please check if you have installed the Odoo17 compatible sassc package also after installation restart your service and try creating a new database.